# Using the result of one query to feed into another query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a compliance rule that checks for a listing of the `sys.traces`

```
SELECT id FROM sys.traces
```

and then use that result to list which trace events have been added to the trace

```
SELECT DISTINCT(eventid) 
FROM sys.fn_trace_geteventinfo(@result from previous query)
```

I want the result to be just a list of trace ids that I can compare to a set requirement.

I'm obviously new to this and have searched but didn't find anything specifically relevant. I know this is an easy one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(eventid) 
FROM sys.fn_trace_geteventinfo(SELECT id FROM sys.traces)  

SELECT DISTINCT(eventid) 
FROM sys.fn_trace_geteventinfo(SELECT top 1 id FROM sys.traces)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select distinct info.eventid
from sys.traces as tr
cross apply sys.fn_trace_geteventinfo (tr.id) as info
```

Comment: I kind of got to this point myself after playing with it for a while. The remaining issue is that I think it's going to need a WHILE loop because there may possibly be more than one returned value from sys.traces (probably more than possible; more likely probable). I know I can get the number of sys.traces rows using the COUNT wrapper so I can structure the loop to only run the query x many times. I just don't know how to embed all of this w/the correct syntax.

Comment: @CaseyStamper Did you even bother to test this?

Comment: Crap. No. I just assumed since I hadn't specified exactly what I was doing that the result wouldn't be correct. This works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Recommendation noted. ;)